# Wine Gaming Problems

Tags: wine, games

Can someone please give me a step by step way in how to use wine I've checked a lot of you tube videos and their pretty old because i'm only seeing people using 32bit installation of it while there's a 64bit as well and I have a 64bit system and because I tried to run Need for Speed Most Wanted on xubuntu while using play on Linux to guide me  and the performance was terrible but on windows it ran normal and someone please guide me in how to properly using it and configuring it please thank you :)

Comment: No i actually haven't tried any linux games but as i watched some youtube with wine it seems pretty smooth to me even smoother than windows but i did realize that linux seems to be running on computers with alot of computing power which i don't necessarily got yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine is not perfect especially for "intensive" programs such as games. Since its not translating every command correctly(or can't translate it at all) there will be problems. For better performance, try turning down every graphics setting you can. Also there are official instructions for wine from winehq.org detailing the process for your system. Ubuntu and other debian based systems should do this.
Purge any previous wine packages with

```
sudo apt purge *wine*
```

Next get the repo info

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt update
```

Then finally install your choice of wine

Stable version

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Staging version:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Development version(not recommended for normal use):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```